# How to make run a for loop in child template of jinja/how to access the variable inside child jinja template which is passed by the python flask file

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

**I am making a child template in jinja which extends the parent template.In child template I am passing a variable to run a for loop in jinja template,but that part of for loop is not accessible inside the html page in chrome.
parent template-In parent template there is only navbar.**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static\navbar.css?v=1.1">  
         {% block head %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li>Website</li>
              <form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" class="search-form"  target="_blank" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Search here..">
                <button>Search</button> 
              </form>
                {% if name %}
                  <li><a href="#">{{name}}</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                {% else %}
                  <li><a href="{{ url_for('open_login') }}">Login & SignUp</a></li>
                {% endif %}

                <li><a href="{{ url_for('display_cart') }}"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></a></li>   
            </ul>
        </nav>

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Child template -In child template i am passing a variable for the for loop,but it is not working.**

```
{% extends 'navbar.html' %}
{% block head %}

        <title>Flipkart</title>
         <!--new version 2nd way to update css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static\gallary.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04c28a3c9a.js"></script>

{% endblock %}
{% block content %}      
    <div class="description">
        Shopping Website
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h2>Deals Of The Day</h2>
    <hr>
    {% for i in ids %}       -----this part is not coming in browser.----
        <h1>sasad<a href="{{ url_for('products_desc', item='shoes', id=i) }}">Link {{i}}</a></h1>

    {% endfor %}
  {% endblock %}
```

**Flask file -- products function**

```
@app.route('/products')
def products():
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM shoes')
    shoes_ids=cursor.fetchall() 

    print(shoes_ids)
    ids = []

    for shoes_id in shoes_ids:
        ids.append(shoes_id['id']) 


    return render_template('navbar.html',ids=ids)   ---here i am passing the 
                                                       variable to the child 
                                                       template-----




I want the for loop content to be displayed on the browser.
```

Comment: Try rendering the child template, and not navbar.html. i.e, `render_template('<child_template_name>.html', ids=ids)`

Comment: @SujanAdiga it is not working.Thankyou